# Spark Code works for 1000 document but as it is increased to 1200 or more it fails with None.get?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, sparkcore

I am developing a application, where i have to read multiple files from HDFS and then process them and save the result in the Cassandra Table.

This is my pseudo code !

```
   val files = sc.wholeTextFiles(s"hdfs://$ipaddress:9000/xhtml/2016/09/*").map(_._1).take(1000)
    val fileNameRDD = sc.parallelize(files)
```

Here i am extracting the path of 1000 documents and then pass into a function that takes path, reads the document , perform the operation and return a case class.

Hence this function is like :

```
def doSomething(path:String):Foo={...}
```

What my biggest concern is the code works fine for 1000 documents ! But as soon as I increase it to 1200 or 1500 it fails with the following exception:

```
[Stage 2:=============================>                            (6 + 6) / 12]16/12/06 11:09:48 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 12, 10.178.149.243): java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to elsevier.rnf.
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:167)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/12/06 11:09:48 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.1 in stage 2.0 (TID 14, 10.178.149.243): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/12/06 11:09:48 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 10 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 10.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 16, 10.178.149.243): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1904)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.knoldus.xml.RNF2Driver$.main(RNFIngestPipeline.scala:38)
    at com.knoldus.xml.RNF2Driver.main(RNFIngestPipeline.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/12/06 11:09:48 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I try to do the Show it displays my document path correctly !

Is there some setting that i am missing ???

I am using Spark 1.6 ! Any help is appreciated !

Comment: so `fileNameRDD` is of type `RDD[String]`? Have you tried to remove `null`s (using e.g. `filter`)?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: Yeah I have tried that already !

Comment: @eliasah : can you help me on this

Comment: Hi Shiva! Got any solution for this ?

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram: No not yet !

Comment: Could you add the detailed body of your method?